# Can't dfferentiate between two selectors meant to perform one specific action

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to click on a button named as `follow` located in a webpage. The thing is when I try with two different selectors, they both can click on the same button.

First selector:

```
"a[href$='/follow']"
```

Second one:

```
"a[href$='/follow'] > button"
```

Portion of relevant html:

```
<div class="nZSzR">
    <h1 class="fDxYl">
        some royal personality
    </h1>
    <span class="VerifiedBadge" title="Verified">
        Verified
    </span>
    <a class="BY3EC" href="/accounts/follow" rel="nofollow">
        <button class="L3NKy" type="button">
            Follow
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

***Which way I should stick to and why?***

Comment: I would first check the events associated to both `a` and `button` and decide which one I have to click on. If you consider the first selector it might not propagate the events that should passed from button. So, I would recommend the second one, if you see any specific events with button. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also point to be noted, both of them have different classes so have to check what is inside those classes to decide which one to be choosed.

Comment: If you've confirmed that they both work, what's the concern?

Comment: Are the classes dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MITHU,

The `css selector` you have `a[href$='/follow']`, represent an **anchor tag** with **href** attribute that ends with `/follow`

second one `a[href$='/follow'] > button` , targets a **button** whose parent is anchor tag.

So, you can clearly see in second css, there is a dependency of a button. So, if you can go ahead with just first you should give priority to that.

For this **HTML** :

```
<a class="BY3EC" href="/accounts/follow" rel="nofollow">
        <button class="L3NKy" type="button">
            Follow
        </button>
</a>
```

Clearly first **css** has less dependency.

If it's anchor tag then answer is no need of **css selector**.

You can directly go ahead with `LINK_TEXT` or `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`

**Sample code :**

```
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Continue')
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Conti')
```

For more go through this official [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: My question is about the differentiation betwen the two for the sake of clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer. I think it will be clear for you now.

Comment: Have you tested and confirmed that by link text will work when the desired text is inside a `BUTTON`? I haven't but I have concerns that it might not work.

Comment: @JeffC :  yes it will work, since button is a child , by default the text between button is accessible to parent which is anchor tag, you can verify that by writing xpath `//a[text()='text']`

Comment: This is [the link](https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?hl=en) in which I was trying to click on the follow button. I've made few modifications in the html, though.

Answer (score 0):

So the > is a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/child_combinator) meaning you will only match the right hand side if it is a child of the left hand side.

Depending on how consistent pages are I would look for a faster selector and in this case go with a third option of

```
#react-root a
```

This is using your link: https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?hl=en

An id and type selector will be faster than especially when using `find_element_by_css_selector` as you only need first match